# Left Join query in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how to query like

`SELECT count(DISTINCT a.client_invoice_id) 
from client_invoice a LEFT JOIN
document b on(a.client_invoice_id = b.relation_id_invoice) 
WHERE a.client_invoice_id IS NOT null
and b.type_document = 'client_invoice'`

in laravel version?

Comment: This is an inner join. If you like, you can prove this by running `EXPLAIN EXTENDED....` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = DB::table('client_invoice as a')
->leftjoin('document as b', 'a.client_invoice_id', '=', 'b.relation_id_invoice')
->whereNotNull('a.client_invoice_id')
->where('b.type_document', '=', 'client_invoice')
->distinct()
->count();
```

Comment: Thanks bro,but how query count(distinct) from those query ?

Comment: i have eror --SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'a.client_invoice' in 'where clause' (SQL: select distinct * from `client_invoice` as `a` left join `document` as `b` on `a`.`client_invoice_id` = `b`.`relation_id_document` where `a`.`client_invoice` is not null and `b`.`type_document` = client_invoice)-- did you know,bro ?

Comment: Check my update. add `->distinc()` before `->count()`;

Comment: Sorry, replace `a.client_invoice` by `a.client_invoice_id`. Just add id at the end on`whereNotNull()`

Answer (score 1):

Laravel left join:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
            ->leftJoin('posts', 'users.id', '=', 'posts.user_id')
            ->get();
```

Or you can use Raw Expression also like:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                     ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count, status'))
                     ->where('status', '<>', 1)
                     ->groupBy('status')
                     ->get();
```

[Laravel Left Join](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

[Laravel Raw Expression](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#raw-expressions)